# localstorage lib that supports like queries

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am looking for a javascript lib that lives on top of `localstorage` that supports `like` queries.

This in itself would be easy to write, but I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

What localstorage libs do people use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an SQL interface in JavaScript, use the [Web SQL Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). I think most browsers support this.

If you want an object database interface, use [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/). This doesn't have a `like` query, but you could store an object that has an index and use that to query.

Comment: **how?** i looked through the code and the only way i can see to do this would be to iterate through all records and and write a custom function to do the `like` match. at that rate, i dont need to use lawnchair, i can use any localstorage lib

Comment: also, it seems that lawnchair doesnt support separate datastores. everything goes into a single bucket, which is not ideal if i want to use it to store city names and dog breeds

Comment: I edited my original answer to better respond to your question. Also, Lawnchair does support multiple datastores.